# Momentum Strategy across all ETFs

Tags: momentum

This strategy is inspired by the Dual Momentum strategy, but instead of comparing US stocks, ex-US stocks and bonds, it expands to all ETFs and takes into account the relative momentum between asset classes, regions, sectors, and leveraged ETFs.

The idea is, that this strategy would take advantage of momentum's industry bets, high beta, as well as business-cycle dependent nature in the most direct way possible.

Would such a strategy, that picks the best-performing ETF every quarter based on 6- and 12-month momentum, make sense for an ultra-aggressive strategy?

Comment: Should depend a lot on the ETFs. For stocks, historically there has been more momentum in individual stocks rather than broad stock market indices.

Comment: I have a friend who likes to do this with Sector SPDR ETFs. https://www.sectorspdr.com/sectorspdr/ I don't know if it has been working well or not.